# jQuery Ajax WCF POST - Return Boolean

Tags: javascript, jquery, wcf

I can't seem to find an example on how to post from jQuery to a WCF web service and capture the returned boolean. This is the code I have so far for returning JSON data:

**Javascript**

```
function VerifyPINData(pin) {
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "http://localhost:8523/WebService/VerifyPINData?pinData=" + pin,
    data: JSON.stringify,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function(data){ alert("result is: " + data); },
    error: function() {alert("error"); },
    complete: function() { alert("complete"); }
});
}
```

**WCF**

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "VerifyPINData?pinData={pinData}")]
    bool VerifyPINData(string pinData);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

Casted the data returned as a boolean:

```
success: function(data){ alert("result is: " + Boolean(data)); },
```

Specified the response as JSON in WCF

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "VerifyPINData?pinData={pinData}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    bool VerifyPINData(string pinData);
```